# Calculating rotor inflow ratio in a helicopter rotor

Tags: aerodynamics, lift

Disclaimer, this is *not* homework.

I am trying to determine the amount of lift force that a rotor on a toy helicopter actually produces.

With some googling, I've learned that the [formula](http://seniorphysics.com/physics/helicopterEEI.pdf) for this is:

$$F=8\,{\pi}^{3}\rho\,{\lambda}^{2}{r}^{4}{f}^{2}$$

Where $f$ is the rate of rotation in Hz, $r$ is the radius of the rotor, $\rho$ is the density of air, and $\lambda$ is the rotor inflow ratio.

$\lambda$ is supposed to be the ratio of the velocity of air moving vertically through the rotor to the velocity of the rim of the rotor.

What I do not know how to calculate is the vertical velocity of the air that the rotor induces on air that passes through it, so I do not know how to calculate $\lambda$, and in turn the force produced by the blades moving at some given speed.   The page from which I obtained the above formula only said that it was "complicated".  I could not find any further details on calculating it except by experimentation.

One can assume in my case that the helicopter has fixed angle blades that are essentially just flat plates.   I can imagine that an upper limit on this velocity would be the rotor's tangential velocity multiplied by the sine of the angle of the blade, but angled blades will invariably produce some drag and I doubt that this upper limit would serve as even a very crude approximation for anything except neglible angles.   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So is $\lambda$ the ratio of induced velocity to $r\omega$? Is it the induced velocity you cannot calculate?

Comment: That's correct.  I realize that it needs to push enough mass through the rotors to at least counter the weight of the helicopter to simply hover, but I am not sure how to calculate how fast that air would actually move given how fast the blades are spinning.